# How to write custom queries in spring CRUD Repository

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing an app using spring Boot.
Here is my code.

```
UserSample.java
@Entity
public class UserSample {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long userId;
    private String userName;

    public UserSample() {
        super();
    }

    public UserSample(String userName) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;

    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
Interface is:


public interface UserSampleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserSample, Long> {

}
```

In main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Autowired
    UserSampleRepository usersampleRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        List<UserSample> userSample = new LinkedList<UserSample>();
        // load data to the table
        userSample.add(new UserSample("user1"));
        userSample.add(new UserSample("user2"));
        usersampleRepo.save(userSample);

        UserSample userInfo = usersampleRepo.findOne(1);

    }

}
```

I am  having in-memory database. Here I am trying to write a query to retrieve by username. like userSampleRepo.findByUserName(String username);
I tried many ways but nothing worked for me.any suggestions?

I tried adding a method in interface .

```
    public interface UserSampleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserSample, Long> {
        UserSample findByUserName(String username);

    }

created another class.

    @Repository
    public class UserSampleRepositoryImpl implements UserSampleRepository {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;

        @Override
        public UserSample findByUserName(String username) {
            TypedQuery<UserSample> query = em.createQuery("select c from UserSample c where c.userName = :username",
                    UserSample.class);
            query.setParameter("username", username);

            return query.getSingleResult();
        }
```

In main class, I used this statement

```
@Autowired
    UserSampleRepositoryImpl usersampleRepo;
    UserSample userInfo = usersampleRepo.findByUserName("user1");
```

I am getting this error:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner"
aused by: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query

Comment: Can you specify - what did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: I added the code I tried.

Comment: That exception means that user with that name doesn't exist in the database

Comment: but I loaded user1 with this statement    userSample.add(new UserSample("user1"));  saved in repo and then trying to findByUserName.

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: Care to share the solution ? You could post the answer and accept it, it could be helpful to future readers.